# How to import solidity libraries in mix?

Tags: solidity, mix, import, library

Working in the MIX environment, I'd like to try using a libraries and contracts defined in different files.  However, the main contract always gets an error from MIX, no matter how I define the "import".  The error is:

```
C:/TryImport/MainContract.sol Error: Source not found: File not supplied initially.
```

If I move the library into the contract file as a test, it compiles and works.

> **File someLib.sol**
>
> > library someLib {...}
>
> **File MainContract.sol**
>
> > import "someLib"
> >
> > contract MainContract {}

Comment: Congratulations for asking the 1000th question on Ethereum Stack Exchange :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it turns out there is an issue in the current release...they have been notified.

The work around is to use the full path.
I also didn't realize that the full path is *case sensitive*.

Answer (score 4):

You can't import `Truffle` libraries to any contract in Mix. The thing is that `Truffle` use your `imports` to build an only `.sol` file, so the compiler doesn't `import` anything. If you want to debug your imports in Mix you should copy your libraries code in the same file than your other contracts.

Comment: Solidity supports imports (or so I thought), and that is what I'm asking about.  Not Truffle imports (which btw it is discontinuing due to Solidity now supporting imports).

Comment: Where do you found it?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `.sol`

```
import "someLib"
```

should be

```
import "someLib.sol"
```

see this [issue](https://github.com/ethereum/mix/issues/290) for reference

Comment: Hi and welcome to Ethereum Stack Exchange! Are you sure this will work? Did you test that? Maybe you could add some explaination to your answer and tell why this is required.

Comment: tried that, fully qualified, ... every permutation I could think of.